# Google Analytics with Next.js

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, google-analytics

I have been trying to use Google Analytics with Next.js and I have configured it by watching this YouTube Video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lMSBNBDjaH8

Based on the video, I added these two scripts in _document.js

```
<script async src={`https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS}`}/>
<script dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                               __html: `
                               window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
                               function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
                               gtag('js', new Date());
                               gtag('config', '${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS}', {
                               page_path: window.location.pathname,
                            });
                          `,
                        }}
                    />
```

Added below code in _app.tsx -

```
useEffect(() => {
    const handleRouteChange = (url: any) => {
      pageview(url);
    };

    //When the component is mounted, subscribe to router changes
    //and log those page views
    router.events.on("routeChangeComplete", handleRouteChange);

    // If the component is unmounted, unsubscribe
    // from the event with the `off` method
    return () => {
      router.events.off("routeChangeComplete", handleRouteChange);
    };
  }, [router.events]);
```

And added below code in lib/ga.ts -

```
export const pageview = (url: any) => {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        (window as any)?.gtag('config', process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS, {
            page_path: url,
        });
    }
};

export const event = ({ action, params }) => {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        (window as any)?.gtag('event', action, params);
    }
};
```

I am facing some issues -

1. If the page does not have a document title, it will not show the page name in the Real-Time tab. Is there any way I can dynamically add document title in each page or page names in google analytics using the url?

[image]

2. For testing, I added document title in one of the pages and it was working in Real-Time tab. But Under Engagement > Pages and Screens tab, I can't see that page name as we can see in the screenshot below.

Require much-needed help if anyone knows how to fix the above issues. Many thanks

[image]

Comment: You need to use the **google tag manager** which is a script that sends events to GA. [Read this](https://medium.com/@pieterjandeclippel/angular-or-react-or-whatever-and-google-analytics-97342c909e61). The guide is for angular, but it really doesn't matter what frontend you write

Comment: It is giving an error when I am adding it to the Next.js project. Where exactly shall I add it in Next.js? I tried it in _document.js file

Comment: Wherever you add external scripts to be loaded in the front-end. It's just a simple <script> tag that you add to DOM, or better yet make sure it's in source. So maybe put it in your html template.

Answer (score 1):

Many things to note here.

1. Real time reports in GA4 are bugged and to be avoided if you can help it. We typically don't use it at all when doing professional enterprise tracking implementations. Instead, we look into Network calls.
2. The Reports section in GA4 is based on poorly aggregated data snapshots. The general advice there is to avoid it and always use the Explorer instead. Explorer is a subject to the data retention setting, but it's much more precise.
3. When you do `gtag('event', action, params)`, gtag pushes the args to the dataLayer, which is being listened to by gtag.js. Gtag.js when it sees something being pushed to DL, grabs that data and starts forming an analytics request. Analytics requests contain a few times more data than what you typically push. Page title is one of them. It tries to grab it for you from the page alongside the url, referrer, useragent and whatnot. Most of these fields can be overriden by setting parameters. Page title can be overriden by setting the page_title parameter. Here's more documentation on the fields: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/reference/config#page_title
4. Overridal like that makes sense if you lack the proper document in your implementation, so like if you're attempting to use gtag.js from the backend.  While it can be done, it's overcomplicated since you'd have to compensate for incorrect/inconsistent client ids and session ids. It's a problem. You likely don't want to go this route.
5. GTM. Use it if you can. It simplifies many things in tracking, abstracting a lot of needless complexity for you. When there's a backend piece of data you need to track, you just send it to your front-end and then it communicates it to GTM through the dataLayer.

Comment: Got some of the points but really not able to get how can I add Pages as mentioned in the screenshot as it is coming in real time data but not in pages and screens. I can also see the path in landing page tab. @BNazaruk

Comment: Oh you have to give the reports time. Up to two days! It's not instant. The hits you see in real time will eventually be reflected in the other reports, but not immediately. Aggregation takes time.

Comment: so why does it show all the data except the page name in **Pages and Screens** Tab. Like it shows the Views, Users, Views per user etc but not the page name.

Comment: you mean screen name and page title? You have screen names if it's an app, you set them explicitly when tracking with firebase SDK. Page titles are tracked automatically from document.title by the library as I described above. Look at your network request to the `collect?` endpoint. the page title dimension is directly linked to the `dt` parameter in the call.

Comment: Page path is in `dp` parameter in the call. It tries to get it from the document.location.pathname

Comment: I am referencing the Pages and Screens tab in the screenshot that I have attached in the question. The page title is in dt and page path is in dp in the network request call as you said. But why is the path or title not coming under the Pages and Screens tab as shown in the screenshot. And why the rest of the data is coming?

Comment: good, now use explorer and try looking at the data through it. As I mentioned, pre-baked pre-aggregated reports are buggy. Once you can confirm that your network requests look good, you wanna go to the Explorer and see the dimensions there. If the explorer doesn't have them either, you made a mistake somewhere. Like maybe you looked at a different site, or maybe you're looking in a wrong GA property, or something like that. The next debugging step would be exporting the data to BQ and seeing if dps and dts are there. But it's usually not needed for simple dimensions' values debugging.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253301/discussion-between-mohit-chauhan-and-bnazaruk).

Comment: I tried just now to select the date as 24th in Explore. I am not able to see any data there

Comment: Not a surprise. The data is not ready.
Google asks for up to 48 hours before the tracked events become available in reports and explorer
Realistically though it usually takes a few hours to appear, but you still shouldn't use super fresh data. It will often be incomplete if even available.